# Horizon: Apache exceptions at import_module

Tags: python, apache2, juju, openstack, django

I've deployed Openstack using juju, and everything looks normal except that I cannot browse to openstack-dashboard. I get error 500 Internal Server Error.

I looked through apache2 logs at that node and found [these errors](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6622389/) repeated every couple of minutes.

I tried to destroy the service and deploy it on other nodes; co-located with keystone node, then glance node, then by it self. Yet I get the same errors.

It looks like it needs deep python debugging which is weird since this is the typical charm deployment on a normal server. And someone must had tried to deploy this and succeeded!

I'm deploying **openstack** Essex version 2012.1.4-dev ,
**Ubuntu** server version 13.10 ,
**django** version is: (1, 5, 4, 'final', 0)
And [this is my **juju status** output](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6622554/)

Please help me :)

Comment: Please edit your question with the version of django you are using. To check the version, open a python interpreter(type python on a terminal) and then the following `import django;django.VERSION`. Paste the output line to your question.

Comment: Also edit your question with the version of openstack(essex, folsom, grizlly, havana(?)) you have installed.

Comment: Thank you @Jobin for the fast response.
Question updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about Essex, but OpenStack Grizzly is not compatible with django 1.5(the version you are using); you need to have django 1.4 installed.

To uninstall django 1.5, open a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type the following:

```
sudo pip uninstall django
```

and then to install django 1.4:

```
sudo pip install django==1.4.10
```

confirm version 1.4 is installed:

```
python
```

you  will get the python interpreter

```
>>> import django;django.VERSION
```

the output should be:

```
(1, 4, 10, 'final', 0)
```

then restart apache service(which uses django):

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Source: [Similar question on OpenStack's official question-answer forum](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/2280/horizon-how-to-fix-cannot-import-force_unicode-in-apaches-errorlog/)

Comment: Super :)
Worked perfectly
Thanks a million my friend

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Comment: You really should **not** be advising to install a django version which lacks several critical security updates! I'll edit your answer.

Comment: @don.joey: Thanks for the edit. Did not know django 1.4.0 had security issues.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you were having is due to a bug in Juju: https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-archive/+bug/1240667, which I just fixed and tested successfully on EC2 using openstack-dashboard charm deployed on the bootstrap node. The fix will be included in the next development (1.17.3) or stable (1.18.0) version of juju-core.

The problem was on precise (12.04) machines, juju was adding the cloud-tools archive to get a version of mongodb-server on precise that works with juju. Now, the cloud-tools pocket is added with lower priority, so that packages in it won't try to interfere with packages from the main archive (used by charms).