# Openstack dashboard error

Tags: python, juju, openstack

Hello I have installed maas,juju and openstack-dashboard. When I try to log in the horizon dashboard I get this error:

```
cannot import name base Request Method: GET Request
URL:    https://htk6y.master/horizon/ Django Version:   1.5.4 Exception
Type:   ImportError Exception Value:     cannot import name base Exception
Location:   /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/api/__init__.py
in <module>, line 36 Python Executable: /usr/bin/python Python
Version:    2.7.3 Python Path:  
['/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../..', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
'/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/', 
'/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard']
```

Can you please give me information what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What does your python code look like? It is saying that there is an import error?

Comment: I don't know where to look at. Can you please tell me?

Comment: This is the same issue as in question http://askubuntu.com/questions/394656/horizon-apache-exceptions-at-import-module/419506. It is due to a juju-core bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-archive/+bug/1240667, which is now fixed and will be included in the next release.